# Background-image not being positionned at right bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'd like to have an image (kind of logo) positioned in the bottom right corner of my page.

The page is very simple:

- the `<html>` (in red in the drawings)
- the `<body>`
- the `<header>`
- the `div#content`

The header is of fixed height. The `#content` can have very different height and it changes dynamically.

The CSS I use:

```
html: {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:url('http://www.imagespourtoi.com/lesimages/mickey/image-mickey-3.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-color: grey;
}

header {
  width: 50%;
  height: 180px;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

On the left is what happened when the `#content` height is bigger than the screen, on the right when it's smaller.
The cloud in the drawing represents the background image. You can see on the left that it's displayed in the bottom right corner of the screen, not of the `<body>` (not the expected behavior).

What am I doing wrong?

NB: I can't reproduce such behavior on JSFiddle.

Comment: Most likely your html and body need the height 100% declaration. `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: sorry, I made the edit (I typed it wrong in the jsFiddle, but right in my css file)

Comment: If I set `height: 100%` to the body element, that won't work when the content is bigger than the screen (it will make the content bigger than the body)

Answer (score 1):

html tag requires a height declaration as well:

`html { height: 100% }`

Comment: sorry, I made the edit (I typed it wrong in the jsFiddle, but right in my css file)